# How to mock private methods in angular jasmine?

Tags: angular

I have a class in typescript that I need to write testing class for.It has a private function *getSourceName* which it calls to set the value of a property.

```
    export class Component implements OnInit {
      sourceNames: Observable<Any[]> = this.getSourceNames();

      constructor(
        private snackbarService: SnackbarService,
        private measureService: MeasureService,
     ) {
       //
     }

     ngOnInit() {
       //
       //
     }

      private getSourceNames(): Observable<Any[]> {

        return this.measureService
          .getData('connectionName')
          .pipe(tap((i) => (this.hideSelected = i.length > 0)))
          .pipe(map(mapSourceToOptions));

      } 
    }
```

How can I create a mock component of this class where the private function will also be mocked? I am currently at this level

```
    describe('Component', () => {
       let component: Component;
       let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
       const mockMeasureService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getData']);
       mockMeasureService.getData.and.returnValue(of([])); 
       await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [Component],
       providers: [
         SnackbarService,
         { provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: {} },
         { provide: MeasureService, useValue: mockMeasureService },
       ],
     }).compileComponents();
    });
```

And I am getting this error

> 

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
at MeasureService.getData (src/app/services/measure.service.ts:43:5)
at Component.getSourceNames (main.js:175555:40)
//
//
//
```

It appears to me I am not mocking the pipe or the private function getSourceNames properly.

Comment: You don't. You either prepare all the data the private method depends on or in this scenario you should mock the call to `measureService.getData` and its return value.

Comment: mock `this.measureService`

Comment: Have you tried with 
`const measureService = TestBed.inject(MeasureService);`
`spyOn(measureService, 'getData').and.raturnValue(of('testOption'));`

Comment: I created a mock for the service called **MeasureServiceMock**. And then used that. It worked for me.